# Why request.UrlReferrer is null in ASP.net while calling the method from Rails console?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 4.0

Case 1) i am calling one URL(it is on .net framework) throw rails console for getting the XML data. but i am getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.

Case 2) If i will make that URL as a link on the website and then i will click on link that time i will get XML data.

```
for ex: <a href="http://localhost:8080/test/affiliate_lead_welcome.aspx?mode=2&affiliate_lead_id=TL1483&username=****.com&password=******/">Lead</a>
```

Here i am getting XML data.

But my requirement is i need data by rails console.(because i need to run background job)

```
1) url = 'http://localhost:8080/test/affiliate_lead_welcome.aspx?mode=2&affiliate_lead_id=TL1483&username=****.com&password=******/'

2) uri = URI.parse(url)

3) request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

4) response = http.request(request)
```

Error i am geting:

```
Line 32:         string username = common.get_request("username");
Line 33:         string password = common.get_request("password");
Line 34:         string host = Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToString(); // Request.UrlReferrer.Host is coming null
```

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Answer (score 0):

Because (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)) `UrlReferrer` is (emphasis is mine):

> Gets information about the URL of the **client's previous request** that linked to the current URL.

From your code there isn't such *previous request* then `UrlReferrer` is `null`. It's right and you can't avoid this but you may handle this special case:

```
string host = Request.UrlReferrer == null ? "localhost" : Request.UrlReferrer.Host.ToString();
```

**Edit**: if you can't change ASP.NET server side code you can insert `Referer` in HTTP headers (yes, it's [mispelled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)):

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.add_field("Referer", "http://localhost:8080")
```

Comment: that URL is 2nd party code i can't change anything in their codebase.

Comment: @RajeshGurbani update my answer, in short: just add (dummy!) Referer HTTP header to your request.

Comment: can you explain this please "request.add_field("Referer", "http://localhost:8080")"

Comment: @RajeshGurbani it's to add a custom HTTP header value (see [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPHeader.html)). There I used a dummy placeholder but it's what ASP.NET application will see in UrlReferrer property.

Comment: [13] pry(main)> res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
=> #<Net::HTTPInternalServerError 500 Internal Server Error readbody=true>

Comment: @RajeshGurbani hard to say with "internal server error". what's exact error message? what's the referrer they expect/allow?

Comment: they are checking with  Request.UrlReferrer.Host.

Comment: @RajeshGurbani I see, from code, but "Internal Server Error" isn't such meaningful. In that dummy url host is "localhost", pick response body...it may contain a full/detailed stack trace.

Comment: req.code itself is 500, i.e Internal server error, so how can i get response body.

Comment: i mean when i am running this "request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)" that time itself i am getting "Internal server error" after that i am adding Referer.

Comment: pry(main)> http = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", 80)
=> #<Net::HTTP localhost:80 open=false>

pry(main)> req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/test/affiliate_lead_welcome.aspx?mode=2&affiliate_lead_id=TL1483&username=***.com&password=*****", {'Referer' => 'www.xyz.com'})
=> #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>

pry(main)> response = http.request(req)
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>

pry(main)> puts response.body
<DETAIL><TRNO>-1</TRNO><TRDATE><TRDATE><STATUS>NO TRANSACTIONS FOUND</STATUS><BOOKING_AMOUNT>-1</BOOKING_AMOUNT></DETAIL>
=> nil

Answer (score 0):

You can get UrlReferrer only when you reached this age upon redirection from any other page. Because this is what UrlReferrer contains (details of the page or Url from where this page was opened).

While in your case you are sending a get request directly from your Rails console which does not provide any refer to your aspx page.

Comment: How can i avoid this?

Comment: Instear of sending a get request directly you can make a page which contains a form with action (Url of your aspx page) and post method set to GET. and then post this form. As per my opinion you can not send a refer directly from Rails console.

Comment: I need to run this method as background job. ex: Every hour this method should call and from this URL i will get XML data, that data i have to store i my database.

Comment: Have you tried setting "HTTP_REFERER" header in your request?

Comment: Well for Rails I don't know the exact syntax but in C# we do it like this WC.Headers.Add("Referer", "http://niksgaur.com/");. Here WC is web client object like you have your request object

Answer (score 0):

If you access the page directly and you **don't** have `request.UrlReferrer` set to anything, this will cause  'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' , as with all things left up to the client, it's variable.  Make sure the `Request.UrlReferer` is set to null.

```
if (!(Request.UrlReferrer == null)) {
    ViewState("url") = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
else {
    ViewState("url") = null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if URL = localhost:80/path/to/the/page.html

http = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", 80)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/path/to/the/page.html", {'Referer' => 'your.site.com'})
response = http.request(req)
puts response.body
```

this is working fine for me.